# How to check if excel column headers are in certain order in apache poi

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

I have to check if certain columns header names are present in an excel sheet in a particular order. The names are : First Name, Last Name(optional), Email Id, Phone No, Address(optional).

I need to check if I the input excel sheet has the mandatory columns as well as any combination of the optional ones.
Ex: First Name, Email Id, Phone No. (All mandatory ones)
    First Name, Last Name, Email Id, Phone
A total of 4 cases are possible.

I have stored the column headers in an arraylist. (If there is an efficient way for my problem statement please let me know!).

```
            public void readAndUpload() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("path.."));
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
    ArrayList<String> headerCell = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    while(cellIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        headerCell.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }

    ArrayList<String> validHeaders = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("First Name", "Email Id","Phone Number"));
    if(headerCell.contains(validHeaders))
    {
        //validation logic here
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Mandatory fields not present");
    }
    file.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your requirement is that you would like to validate the following things,
1. If the headers in the excel are permitted headers (mandatory and optional).
2. If the mandatory headers are present.
3. If the mandatory headers are in order.

Here is one solution.

```java
public class HeaderProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> headersFromExcel = Arrays.asList("EMail", "Phone", "Address", "Last Name", "First Name");
        System.out.println(validate(headersFromExcel));
    }

    private static boolean validate(List<String> headers) {
        List<String> mandatoryHeaders = Arrays.asList("First Name", "EMail", "Phone");
        List<String> optionalHeaders = Arrays.asList("Last Name", "Address");
        List<String> allHeaders = new ArrayList<>(mandatoryHeaders);
        allHeaders.addAll(optionalHeaders);
        Map<String, Integer> headerIndexMap = IntStream.range(0, headers.size())
                                                    .boxed()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> headers.get(i), i -> i));


        if(!allHeaders.containsAll(headers)) {
            System.out.println("Some headers exist which are not allowed");
            return false;
        }

        if (!headers.containsAll(mandatoryHeaders)) {
            System.out.println("Mandatory headers are not present");
            return false;
        }

        System.out.println(mandatoryHeaders.stream()
                .map(headerIndexMap::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // Check if the manadatory headers are in order
        Integer result = mandatoryHeaders.stream()
                        .map(headerIndexMap::get)
                        .reduce(-1, (x, hi) -> x < hi ? hi : headers.size());


        if (result == headers.size()) {
            System.out.println("Mandatory headers are not in order");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here, I have assumed that the headersFromExcel field is the list of headers extracted from your excel.

One more thing, in your code you have used,

```html
if(headerCell.contains(validHeaders))
```

Here, you should use containsAll() instead of contains(), because contains will consider the passed argument as one object and will compare with every individual cell of the ArrayList and will return always false in your case.

Comment: Ah, yes it is containsAll, I posted the previous version of the code which used contains. Will try the solution you suggested now